# Centering multiple JLabels in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, centering

I have a JPanel that is displaying multiple JLables which each represent a character of a binary string. (They are all individual because each must have a MouseListener, but this is not part of my problem)

My problem is that I can't seem to center the JLables.

I have tried

```
this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
add(label1);   //= left aligned
label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);  //= still left aligned
```

and

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);  //= only 1 showed up
```

I have also left it as default FlowLayout, but for some reason, this ignores the size and spaces the jLabels out so they don't all fit on the row they are suppose to. I also tried putting a FlowLayout inside a Boxlayout. Still didn't work.

PLEASE NOTE, in my examples above, I have more than one label (I actually have 31!!)

How should I get this to work?

EDIT: updated where I copied wrong code. label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT)

EDIT: The jLabels need to be in a horizontal row, not column.

Comment: What's the value of `alignment` in your first code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd suggest maybe a single column `GridLayout`, with the label text centered.

Comment: @TedHopp whoops, copied the code wrong. Its updated.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, the jLabels need to be all on the same row.

Comment: *"I guess I should have specified,.."*  ASCII art or a drawn image (linked).

Answer (score 1):

The layout for `BoxLayout` need to be along the `Y_AXIS` for any center alignment to work. In the case of `BorderLayout`, while 3 components can be placed horizontally(`WEST`, `CENTER`, `EAST`) they are not distributed evenly. Similarly, `FlowLayout`, while allowing components to be center aligned, does not distribute them evenly.

The simplest approach would be to use a `GridLayout`:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout());
label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: I added an Edit... I assumed saying I wanted to represent binary would mean I want all the labels horizontal. Also, FlowLayout doesn't actually seem to want to respect my preferred size.